# How do i import json file that was exported from parse.com into mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I exported our collections from parse.com and they are bunch of json files ranging from few hundred megs to few gigabytes. 
How would I import them onto a local mongo database?

I tried running

```
mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --file file.json --jsonArray
```

but that did not work because i got an error saying jsonArray too large.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Both of the answers here are incorrect as `mongoimport` handles this use case just fine. MongoDB has no limit (aside from those of your own computer) as to how much data can be loaded into a database.

It is true that document size is indeed limited to 16mb by MongoDB BUT the Parse platform limits document size to 128kb so there is no chance that a even the largest Parse document(object) will exceed MongoDB's 16mb constraint.

Now, to import data from exported from Parse into MongoDB (I've succesfully done this with a multi GB export) I was able to use the `--jsonArray` option by removing the enclosing `result: { }` that Parse's export tool puts around the JSON objects. I also put all the options before the filename:

```
mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --jsonArray file.json`
```

You can easily strip the enclosing result object with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as mentioned in the comments using the following command if you have a lot of collections to process:

```
jq .results <collectionFromParse.json>
```

Comment: this was an issue in the old mongoimport code that I'm pretty sure you and I resolved in 2014 -- if the whole import was on oneline like the mongoimport code would incorrectly error out.

Comment: Worth noting for mongo beginners that `mongoimport` is a command to be run in the local shell like `mongo`, not something that you use after connecting via `mongo`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can strip the `results` key via `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with the command `jq .results <collectionFromParse.json>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that jsonArray is limited to 16mb total.

You can still use mongoimport but you'll need to make sure each document is on a single line and that the results key is removed.

You can do this with sed and stream the results into mongoimport.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Tyler, but as a notes-to-self entry, if you want to replicate a Parse data set on a machine for use with Parse-Server, you also need to map Parse's `objectId` indices to Mongo's `_id` indices.  There are many ways; I just piped it through sed, as below:

```
# brew install jq # (if on a Mac)
sed -e 's/\"objectId\":/\"_id\":/g' <collection.json> \
    | jq .results | mongoimport -d <DatabaseName>
```

Comment: Im having this problem triying your code: exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Field name expected: offset:3 of:  {

Answer (score -1):

The `--jsonArray` option restricts the import to 16MB and expects the import of multiple MongoDB documents in one json array. In general, documents in MongoDB have a 16MB size limit. You'll have to modify the json files and design your schema so each document is < 16MB.

Comment: each document is far below 16 MB. I wonder if it has to do with how parse exports it.

Comment: The *total* size of the jsonArray import is limited to 16MB. See [--jsonArray](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--jsonArray).